# Open new file without switching tab from Find Results panel

Tags: sublime-text-3

In Sublime Text 3, I can open files from the 'Find Results' panel by double clicking the file path.  This opens the file in a new tab.  Is it possible to open a new tab for this file, without automatically switching focus away from Find Results?